# watermelondb warning - multiple readers/writers

Tags: javascript, rocket.chat, watermelondb

I'm getting the following warning and I don't know what can be the cause for it
[image]

Anyone ran into this warning?

Thanks

I'm working on rocketchat instance and this warning is just keep popup once in a while

Comment: Please do not post code or errors as images https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.